# Jacoco vs Surefire

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I might not sound correct in my question but hope I will get some help in this respect too.

Jacoco is mainly for Code Coverage, does this mean that whether the test cases run or not (through surefire plugin) the coverage will be shown in SONAR?

If I do not run any of the test cases via surefire plugin, then also the code coverage would remain the same?

Thank you guys for inputs.

Answer (score 4):

SONAR can show the test coverage in two different ways. The first is by using/consuming coverage reports generated locally (using pluiging like jacoco). The second option or configuration is sonar itself can run its embedded engine to execute tests and coverage reports. 
As a developer , if you would like to run tests locally hence see and improve the coverage result, it is a good idea to use the first approach.
To sum it up, sonar can show the coverage results even if you don't run jacoco locally .